# Is InputDate broken in Blazor .NET 7.0 when using nullable DateTime?

Tags: datetime, blazor, datetimepicker, .net-7.0

I've recently upgraded our blazor solution to .NET 7.0 using the upgrade tool.
Since this upgrade our InputDates are throwing an error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'type' on object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputDate`1[[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'type' on object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputDate`1[[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
```

This has only happened since the upgrade to .NET 7 and was working fine previously on .NET 5. I can't find any upgrade notes to say there is a change here.

What do I need to do in .NET 7.0 to support nullable datetimes using the InputDate component?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The error is also happening for non-nullable DateTimes too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue.
The problem was setting type="date" on the  tag.

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="@RegisterModel.DateOfBirth" @onfocusin="DobFocusIn" id="DateOfBirth" type="date" aria-required="true"></InputDate>
```

Needs to be

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="@RegisterModel.DateOfBirth" @onfocusin="DobFocusIn" id="DateOfBirth" aria-required="true"></InputDate>
```